# Extracting data from a web page using BS4 in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from this site: http://www.afl.com.au/fixture

in a way such that I have a dictionary having the date as key and the "Preview" links as Values in a list, like

```
dict = {Saturday, June 07: ["preview url-1, "preview url-2","preview url-3","preview url-4"]}
```

Please help me get it, I have used the code below:

```
def extractData():
    lDateInfoMatchCase = False
#     lDateInfoMatchCase = []
    global gDict
    for row in table_for_players.findAll("tr"):
        for lDateRowIndex in row.findAll("th", {"colspan" : "4"}):
            ldateList.append(lDateRowIndex.text)

    print ldateList
    for index in ldateList:
        #print index
        lPreviewLinkList = []
        for row in table_for_players.findAll("tr"):
            for lDateRowIndex in row.findAll("th", {"colspan" : "4"}):

                if lDateRowIndex.text == index:
                    lDateInfoMatchCase = True
                else:
                    lDateInfoMatchCase = False

             if lDateInfoMatchCase == True:
                     for lInfoRowIndex in row.findAll("td", {"class": "info"}):
                         for link in lInfoRowIndex.findAll("a", {"class" : "preview"}):
                             lPreviewLinkList.append("http://www.afl.com.au/" + link.get('href'))
        print lPreviewLinkList
        gDict[index] = lPreviewLinkList
```

My main aim is to get the all player names who are playing for a match in home and in away team according to date in a data structure.

Comment: Why do all your variables have `l` at the beginning? Please consider going over the [python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Actually `l` helps me recognize whether it is local  variable... I can refactor the name if you say

Comment: You defeated the purpose because `global lDict` is not a local variable.

Comment: sorry for this, I have corrected it now

Comment: Naming your variable `dict` is also not a good idea, because it shadows a built-in keyword.

Comment: Anyway, local variables are the norm in Python. If you need a reminder, I'd strongly suggest a fugly naming convention for *global* variables instead.

Comment: I will have a look on it, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using [CSS Selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). Select the first table, then all rows in the `tbody` for ease of processing; the rows are 'grouped' by `tr th` rows. From there you can select all next siblings that don't contain `th` headers and scan these for preview links:

```
previews = {}

table = soup.select('table.fixture')[0]
for group_header in table.select('tbody tr th'):
    date = group_header.string
    for next_sibling in group_header.parent.find_next_siblings('tr'):
        if next_sibling.th:
            # found a next group, end scan
            break
        for preview in next_sibling.select('a.preview'):
            previews.setdefault(date, []).append(
                "http://www.afl.com.au" + preview.get('href'))
```

This builds a dictionary of lists; for the current version of the page this produces:

```
{u'Monday, June 09': ['http://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/12/melb-v-coll'],
 u'Sunday, June 08': ['http://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/12/gcfc-v-syd',
                      'http://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/12/fre-v-adel',
                      'http://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/12/nmfc-v-rich']}
```

Comment: what are the modules u needed to import in your code?

Comment: @Anand: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. You stated you were using BeautifulSoup 4. No other libraries are being used here.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. But the dictionary doesn't have friday and saturday data. How to have those too?

Comment: @Anand: there are no preview links for those days. You can just do `preview[date] = []` and replace `preview.setdefault(date, []).append` with `preview[date].append` if you wanted empty lists for those.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learnt from you. I had no idea of using `table.fixture`,`tbody tr th`, etc

Comment: @Anand: that's a CSS selector; there are 3 such tables (one for each of the tabs in the rendered page); this just picks the first one.

Comment: I will study about CSS selector. Now I need to get all players name who are playing for a certain match using the preview link. What if I am stuck, can I ask you here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55250/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-anand).

Comment: Ask a new question, comments are not the place for such extensive follow-ups, really.

Comment: I mis tapped on my smartphone screen; I did not mean to create a chat room. Sorry!

Comment: Okay then I will post new question, if I am stuck. Thanks